# I'm trying to create a ticket system using JDA (Discord development); Trouble with variables

Tags: java, discord, ticket-system, discord-jda

So, I have multiple public variables, but if one has multiple tickets open, the variables are shared between tickets, since it is the same script, which breaks the program since variables need to be reset at ticket creation. I was thinking if I could use objects, but I haven't the faintest idea how to implement that. Here's my code: https://paste.myst.rs/dj7

Comment: You'd need, at the very least, a `Ticket` class, plus some sort of repository (could be as simple as a list or as complex as a relational database) to store the tickets in. I strongly suggest you brush up on your OOP basics.

Comment: Ok thank you! I didn't think I would need a database, but you're right. My system creates a ticket transcript, so I can just send that into another discord channel. Anyways, thank you again!

Comment: If you "store" your tickets by writing them into a discord channel, then it is still sensible to have a repository class which handles saving and loading the tickets from there, and possibly caches them in-memory for increased performance.